# How to install font-awesome in Visual Studio 2017 using ASP.NET Core v2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, npm, visual-studio-2017, bower, font-awesome

I am building a webpage using ASP.NET Core v2 and would like to use font-awesome.

First let me say that I have tried several things. like installing Bower from NPM, installing font-awesome from NPM, installing font-awesome from Bower packages in VS but nothing seem to work.

can someone please provide the correct way to install font-awesome, (preferred without using a lot of console commands or manual copying of files.)

This is what my depedencises currently looks like

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to install it using NuGet? https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome/

Comment: Well, that did install the package as Nuget, but how do I enable it on my web page?

Comment: You should refer font- awesome CSS on your page header `<link href="../Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Check my answer for more details and example

Comment: well, the problem is that I do not see the font-awesome css or any of the other fa files. so pointing to a content folder will not help. all I see after installtion is Dependecies\NuGet\FontAwesome package

Comment: In .Net core this files will be add under the following path `C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\fontawesome\4.7.0`

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend using LibMan for this ([Short documentation how to use it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2)).

I wrote it manually, bet you could add it through "Add -> Client-Side Library". Here is mine libman.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
    "libraries": [
        {
            "library": "font-awesome@4.7.0",
            "destination": "wwwroot/lib/font-awesome",
            "files": [
                "css/font-awesome.min.css",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2",
                "fonts/FontAwesome.otf"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for VS2017 and VS2019 users

Comment: This is for now the best answer, @David, he is correct bower is deprecated:   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/what-happened-to-bower/ and some extra info (for those in need of a simpler solution) https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager

Answer (score 5):

`Bower` is going away. `NuGet` now focus on .NET packages so your best bet to get `font-awesome` is via `NPM`.

### 1.Download NPM

Make sure you have the latest `nodejs` installed. Navigate to https://nodejs.org/en/ and download the LTS version.

To check the version of `node` as well as `npm` installed on your machine:

1. Right click your project in Visual Studio
2. Select "Open Command Line"
3. Select "Default (Cmd)" (or whatever command prompt you want to use)
4. Run command `node -v` and `npm -v`

[image]

### 2. Add `package.json`

You need to have the npm configuration file to your project. This configuration file lists out all your packages and is used by npm to restore packages when it needs to.

To add the npm configuration file:

1. Right click your project in visual studio
2. Select "Add" -> "New Item"
3. Select "ASP.NET Core" on the left and search "npm" on the search bar on the top right
4. Hit "Add"

[image]

### 3. Install font-awesome (and others)

Open `package.json` and under `devDependencies`, just by typing `"font-awesome":`, it should automatically give you a list of available versions you can pick. Pick a version you like.

By saving this `package.json` file, the `npm` will download the libraries listed into the hidden `node_modules` folder under your project.

[image]

### 4. Copy files to wwwroot

In ASP.NET Core MVC applications, if you want to use static contents like styles and javascript files, beside you need to enable `app.UseStaticFiles();` in the `Startup.cs`, you also need to copy the files to the wwwroot folder. By default, the content, for example, in `node_modules` are not serviceable to your application.

You can of course manually cope the files you want into wwwroot folder. But then you will have to replace the files whenever there are new versions come out.

To **properly** copy the files, we need to use 3rd party tooling!

[BundlerMinifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) is a great tool you can use to bundle files you want and output them to the directories you want. It uses similar configuration file called `bundleconfig.json`:

[image]

But this tool doesn't work well with file types other than `.css` and `.js`. There is also an issue of relative url to the font-awesome fonts folder because the font-awesome style uses `url();` (setting `"adjustRelativePaths": false` doesn't always work).

### 5. Create Gulp tasks

To **properly** move font-awesome files and fonts to wwwroot folder, I can use `gulp` to set up tasks I can run before build, after build, etc:

#### 5.1. Install `gulp` (and `rimraf`, the unix command `rm -rf`)

Go to `package.json` and type `gup` and `rimraf` in the dependency list. Save the file.

[image]

#### 5.2. Add `gulpfile.js` to your project and define tasks

I basically need to create a task to move font-awesome to wwwroot/libs folder, and create another task to do the reverse for cleanup. I omitted other tasks not related to font-awesome.

[image]

#### 5.2.1 UPDATE for Gulp +v4.0:

gulp from gulp v4.0 Use `gulp.series()` to combine multiple tasks
so if you are using Gulp +v4.0 you should update your code as below:

```js
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
    'copy:font-awsome'
));

gulp.task('clean', gulp.series(
    'clean:font-awesome'
));
```

#### 5.3 Run tasks

After you have setup the `gulpfile.js`, you should be able to see the tasks listed in "Task Runner Explorer". If you don't have that window in Visual Studio, Go to "View" -> "Other Windows".

[image]

You can manually run any task by right clicking it and hit "Run". Or you can have it run automatically when before build, after build, clean or project open.

After you setup the bindings, a header would be added to the `gulpfile.js`:

[image]

Now save the `gulpfile.js` file and build your project. Your font-awesome files and fonts should be automatically moved to the wwwroot and ready to use.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0.8, on Windows 10, and just struggled to get FA in to my project too. I was able to add it to NPM by adding it to the package.json (as others have mentioned) under dependencies, like this:

```js
    {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "name": "asp.net",
      "private": true,
      "devDependencies": {},
      "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3"
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, although it restored the package, it didn't deploy the css files where I had expected, so that I could reference them. I don't believe the following is anything like the "correct" way to do it (still learning!), however, it worked for me.

In Solution Explorer:

- Navigate to **Dependencies** > **npm**
- Right-Click **font-awesome** > **Open in File Explorer**
- Go in to the **css** folder
- Copy the .css files
- Back in **Visual Studio**, in **Solution Explorer**, navigate to **wwwroot**
- Right-Click **css** > **Open in File Explorer**
- Paste in the files

You can now drag these in to your project to make references to them, and start using Font Awesome, like this:

_Layout.cshtml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] websiteTitle</title>
    
        <environment include="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
            <link href="~/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        </environment>
    </head>
```

Hope this is of some help to anyone stopping by like I was.

Comment: Hope we can still find the "proper" way to do this.

Comment: The easiest way is to use LibMan as answered below by @Aleksej Vasinov. It support both VS2017 and VS2019. Refer the link provided to Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Go to package.json

add the following tag **"font-awesome": "^4.7.0"** in **dependencies** section

Eg :-

```
  {
  "name": "imsy-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ng5-breadcrumb": "0.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a recommendation from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bootstrap)

> The recommended way to install client-side dependencies like Bootstrap
>   in ASP.NET Core is via Bower (using `bower.json`)

Open the `bower.json` file and add `font-awesome` to the dependencies

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "Font-Awesome": "4.3.0"
  }
}
```

Open the `.bowerrc` file under `bower.json`, The `directory` property is set to `wwwroot/lib` which indicates the location Bower will install the package assets.

```
{
 "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

Now you can refer font-awesome as below

```
<link href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The easiest way to get started with Font Awesome is to add a reference to it, using its public content delivery network (CDN) location:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

For more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower

Answer (score 0):

No coding is necessary using this approach in Visual Studio.
Select the web project in Solution explorer and right click and choose Add and then Client-Side Library. This will also add the necessary content to libman.json file.

Choose Unpkg and then search for : Font Awesome.
Just select version 4.7 like this for example (Click on picture to zoom in):
[image: Adding Font awesome]

After that you can add icons like in this example in a Razor file:

```
  <button class="btn btn-success col-md-3 offset-3"><i class="fa-cloud-download fa"></i>&nbsp;Load data</button>
```

Note that we use 'fa' and then we can add the icons with CSS classes starting with 'fa-'.

Easy !

Disclaimer: This might work best in VS 2019, not VS 2017..